Finding lowest common ancestor for more than two nodes
Finding lowest common ancestor for two nodes is:
MATCH (c {id: id1})<-[*]-(x)-[*]->(d {id: id2}) RETURN x 

How can we extend this to find lowest common ancestor given a list of ids in a directed tree graph?

Updated answer
To get the lowest common ancestor of all of the nodes whose ids are supplied in a single list:
WITH [10, 2] AS ids
UNWIND ids AS id1
UNWIND ids AS id2
WITH id1, id2 WHERE id1 <> id2
MATCH ({id: id1})<--*(x)-->*({id: id2})
WITH collect(DISTINCT x) AS candidates
UNWIND candidates AS c
WITH c WHERE all(d IN candidates WHERE EXISTS { (c)-->*(d) })
RETURN candidate

These are the steps:

Form a Cartesian product of the node ids, minus the diagonal, with each pair in variables id1 and id2.

Find the lowest ancestor of each pair of node ids. Collect these into a list of distinct nodes assigned to variable candidates. Our answer must be one of these nodes.

Unwind these candidates and filter on the candidate that has all the other nodes as a descendent (or is itself). Only one node will satisfy this condition.


This uses a quantified relationships, which requires version 5.9+. For earlier versions you can replace the pattern in the MATCH statement with the pattern ({id: id1})<-[*0..]-(x)-[*0..]->({id: id2}).

Thank you for the answer. What if I only have a single list of ids?

I’ve added a third UNWIND example to answer your question.

Nice to know that's how you do a cartesian product of a list with itself. But the query actually generates a union of ancestors rather than the lowest common ancestor.

Are you looking for the lowest common ancestor of all the nodes in the list?

I am. Is that possible? I was under the impression that it was a common problem

Ah OK, now I get it. See the updated answer.

Thanks a lot. That works. But I had to change the second to last line to WITH c WHERE all(d IN candidates WHERE EXISTS { (c)-->*(d) }).
Changed c to candidates since c is a single node

Another way to accomplish this would be to find intersection of ancestors of each node and find the lowest node in that node chain.
MATCH (a WHERE a.id in $idList)<--*(p)
WITH  a, COLLECT(p) as ancestors
WITH COLLECT(ancestors) as ancestorsPerNode
WITH reduce(commonAncestors = head(ancestorsPerNode), ancestor in tail(ancestorsPerNode) |  apoc.coll.intersection(commonAncestors, ancestor) ) as candidates
UNWIND candidates as c
WITH c WHERE all(d IN candidates WHERE EXISTS { (c)<--*(d) })
RETURN c

These are the steps:

Find ancestors of all nodes

Group ancestor by node

Find intersection between the ancestors per node to get a list of common ancestor.

Filter the list of common ancestor to find the node that is descendant of  all other nodes in the list or lowest common ancestor


Though this uses the reduce function and apoc's intersection procedure, I think this aligns more with the name "Lowest common ancestor" since it finds the common ancestors and then the lowest among them.
